# How to choose the boundaries for the outliers in the pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with the pandas `DF` and the properties are following,

`df.info()` prints before entering the outlier function,

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6661 entries, 0 to 6660
Data columns (total 4 columns):
currency       6661 non-null object
port           6661 non-null object
supplier_id    6661 non-null int64
value          6661 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 260.2+ KB
None
```

`df.columns.values` prints,

```
[u'currency' u'port' u'supplier_id' u'value']
```

the data was like before adding the `country` and the `outlier` comlumns,

```
currency   port  supplier_id   value
0         USD  CNAQG           35  118.66
1         USD  CNAQG           19  120.83
2         USD  CNAQG           49   86.83
3         USD  CNAQG           54  112.15
4         USD  CNAQG          113  113.60
5         USD  CNAQG            5  114.32
6         USD  CNAQG           55  111.43
7         USD  CNAQG           81  117.22
8         USD  CNAQG            2  111.43
9         USD  CNAQG           10  119.39
10        USD  CNAQG           56  104.91
11        USD  CNAQG           14  119.39
12        USD  CNAQG            4  115.77
13        USD  CNAQG            7  119.39
14        USD  CNAQG           74  127.34
15        USD  CNAQG           15  112.15
16        USD  CNAQG          149   88.27
17        USD  CNAQG           20  144.71
18        USD  CNAQG          231  119.39
19        USD  CNBIH           19  140.00
```

I use lower and the upper quartile `0.05` and `0.95` respectively and use the formula to exclude the outliers,

```
CURRENCIES_DIC = {'CN':'CHINA', 'US':'USA'}

LOW_Q = 0.05
HIGH_Q = 0.95



#  mark the data for respective country as outlier 
def calculate_outliers(df):

    df['country'] = df.port.str[:2].map(CURRENCIES_DIC)
    df['outlier'] = 0

    for c in df.country.unique():
        q = df.value[df.country==c].quantile([LOW_Q, HIGH_Q])
        df.loc[df.index[df.country==c], 'outlier'] = (df.value[df.country==c].apply(lambda x: 1 if x<q[LOW_Q] or x>q[HIGH_Q] else 0))
    
    return df
```

1. How to choose the correct values for defining the outliers ?
2. Is there any better way to define the outliers for the respective purpose ?

   I see another formula `df[np.abs(df.Data-df.Data.mean())<=(3*df.Data.std())] #keep only the ones that are within +3 to -3 standard deviations in the column 'Data'.` Would it be better to use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, there is no general rule for defining correct thresholds which distinguish between *normal* values and *outliers*. In fact, there are plenty of different methods to detect outliers. Wikipedia has a good coverage [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier#Detection).

What outliers actually mean is highly dependent on your context. Plotting your data helps to get a visual impression of how your data *behaves*. In case your data is not normally distributed, the standard deviation criteria might not be well suited as the data is not symmetrically distributed.

See those two topics on crossvalidated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38001/detecting-outliers-using-standard-deviations) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37865/is-there-a-simple-way-of-detecting-outliers) for more.

You can slightly modify your code to make it a bit more readable:

```
CURRENCIES_DIC = {'CN':'CHINA', 'US':'USA'}
LOW_Q = 0.05
HIGH_Q = 0.95

def outlier_quant(series):
    lower = series < series.quantile(LOW_Q)
    upper = series > series.quantile(HIGH_Q)
    return lower | upper

def mark_outliers(sub_df)
    sub_df["country"] = sub_df["port"].str[:2].map(CURRENCIES_DIC)
    sub_df["outlier"] = sub_df.groupby("country")["value"].transform(outlier_quant)

print(mark_outliers(df))
```